# Passing String value to Dynamicaly created HTML Element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have Array msg i want to pass this to onclick function of dynamicaly created Element in html.

```
for(var i=0; i < msg.length ; i++){

 categoryList += "<img src='../products/"+msg[i].imgurl+"' class='slide_contain' onclick='getCanvas("+msg[i].id+","+msg[i].shape+","+msg[i].height+","+msg[i].width+","+msg[i].topval+","+msg[i].leftval+","+msg[i].radius+","+msg[i].subcat+","+msg[i].imgurl+")'/>";
    categoryList += "<li> <span> "+msg[i].imgurl+"</span></li>";
}
```

**On inspection i see :**

```
<img src="../products/Lighthouse.jpg" class="slide_contain" onclick="getCanvas(2,3,100,100,100,210,100,1,Lighthouse.jpg)">
```

Here last variable which is string is not passed correctly ?? how to do it ?
or Else how can i pass msg Array to function and fetch values in function ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like this

```
categoryList += '<img src="../products/'+msg[i].imgurl+' class="slide_contain" onclick="getCanvas('+msg[i].id+','+msg[i].shape+','+msg[i].height+','+msg[i].width+','+msg[i].topval+','+msg[i].leftval+','+msg[i].radius+','+msg[i].subcat+',\''+msg[i].imgurl+'\')"/>';
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the quotes..

```
 categoryList += "<img src='../products/"+msg[i].imgurl+"' class='slide_contain' onclick='getCanvas("+msg[i].id+","+msg[i].shape+","+msg[i].height+","+msg[i].width+","+msg[i].topval+","+msg[i].leftval+","+msg[i].radius+",'"+msg[i].subcat+"')'/>";
```

Comment: no not working .. i get <img src="../products/Lighthouse.jpg" class="slide_contain" onclick="getCanvas(2,3,100,100,100,210,100,1," lighthouse.jpg')'>

Answer (score 0):

Pass you last argument this way ==>

```
  \'' msg[i].subcat  '\' 
 categoryList += "<img src='../products/"+msg[i].imgurl+"' class='slide_contain' onclick='getCanvas("+msg[i].id+","+msg[i].shape+","+msg[i].height+","+msg[i].width+","+msg[i].topval+","+msg[i].leftval+","+msg[i].radius+",' \''"+msg[i].subcat+"'\' ')'/>";
```

OutPut

```
'Lighthouse.jpg'
```